# Remove buttons md-autofocus from a custom md-dialog

Tags: mddialog

I have a this md-dialog https://codepen.io/patapron/pen/oLaxap

```
<md-button ng-click="answer('not useful')" >
 Not Useful
</md-button>
<md-button ng-click="answer('useful')" style="margin-right:20px;" >
  Useful
</md-button>
```

How do to I get remove the md-autofocus from the buttons?

Objetive: Any button must be pre-selected paint in grey.

Comment: I tried with a directive removing the attrib "md-autofocus" to the buttons but doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier way to do this without having to write a custom directive. Angular Material has the ability to remove autofocus built-in.

In your controller where you are writing the .show function, set the focusOnOpen to false `focusOnOpen: false`

The documentation explains it here [$mdDialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)

[image]

Here is an example of how mine looks

```
    function deleteMediaDialog() {
        var dialogData = {
        };

        $mdDialog.show({
            controller         : 'deleteMediaDialogController',
            controllerAs       : 'vm',
            templateUrl        : 'app/main/apps/scala-media/dialogs/delete/delete-dialog.html',
            parent             : angular.element($document.body),
            focusOnOpen        : false,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            locals             : {
                dialogData: dialogData
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by mysleft. Directive magic

```
scope.$watch(function () { return ele.attr('class'); }, function () {
    if (ele.hasClass('md-focused')) {
        ele.removeClass('md-focused');
    }
});
```